# Locality and code optimization

Tags: optimization, gcc, assembly, spatial

Can optimizers get rid of bad uses of spatial locality? I'm maintaining some code written by somebody else, and many of their arrays are declared in haphazard orders, and iterated differently every time they are called.

Because of the complexity of the code it would be quite the block of time to try and remanage every time the arrays were cycled. I'm not skilled enough at reading assembly language to be able to tell exactly whats different with varying levels of optimization, but my question is,

Is locality important when writing programs, or does that get optimized away so I can not worry about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few to none compiler handle data layout for locality. It's still an active research domain.

Comment: Do you have any citations for this claim?

Answer (score 3):

Getting locality right is important, because it can make a difference of two orders of magnitude (5-6 orders of magnitude if you have page faults) of difference in runtime.

Apart from the fact that *real* compilers usually don't handle this automatically (as Joel Falcou said), even a *hypothetical* compiler would have a very hard time doing such a thing. In many cases, it may not even be valid for the compiler to do such a thing, and it is **very hard** to predict when it is or when it is not.

Say, for example, you have vertex data that you calculate on the CPU, and which you upload to a graphics API such as OpenGL or DirectX. You've agreed with that API a certain vertex data layout. Now the compiler figures that it is more efficient to rearrange the layout in some way. Bang, you're dead.
How was the compiler supposed to know?

Say you have a few arrays and a few pointers, and some pointers alias others, or some point into the middle of an array for some reason, others point at the beginning. The compiler figures that it's more efficient to do certain operations in a different order, overwriting one result with another.
The data corruption issue left aside, let's say those arrays are "somewhat big", so they're most certainly going to be dynamically allocated rather than being on the stack. Which means their start addresses are "non-deterministic" or even "random" from the compiler's point of view. How is the compiler going to make decisions -- at compile time -- not knowing half of the details?

Comment: Good points. (Not in my case), but for arguments sake, what about a static sized array? Since there would be more of a pattern, would a compiler be able to chew out that one? (Not needed for my project, just a curiosity question)

Comment: Again, for _existing_ compilers, it's a definite "no". A _hypothetical_ compiler could in principle do such a thing as long as it complies with the language specification, and as long as the externally observeable behaviour is 100% identical. However, this is still a hard problem. How is the compiler supposed to deal with multithreading? Usually this is something compilers don't care about (and don't need to), as the programmer is responsible for e.g. filling a buffer and then signalling another thread to read it. Now what if the compiler reordered the structures differently in two threads...